# Why would one reference the node on itself?

Tags: memgraphdb

I get why would someone use code like this

```
CREATE (a:Node {name: "Node A"})-[:RELATIONSHIP_TYPE]->(b:Node {name: "Node B"})-[:RELATIONSHIP_TYPE]->(c:Node {name: "Node C"})
CREATE (c)-[:RELATIONSHIP_TYPE]->(a)
```

I don't understand when would someone use self-reference form node to node itself

```
CREATE (a:Node {name: "Node A"})-[:RELATIONSHIP_TYPE]->(a)
```

What would be some real world scenario for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A self-reference in a graph database can be useful in certain scenarios where an entity has a relationship with itself. Social networks is the first scenario that comes to my mind. User might want to follow their own updates or activities.

You could represent this self-following relationship with a self-reference. Here's an example of such query:

```
CREATE (u:User {name: "Alice"})-[:FOLLOWS]->(u)
```

You have one node (User `Alice`) with the label `User` and a property `name` set to "`Alice`". On top of it you have a relationship of type `FOLLOWS` from User Alice to itself, representing that `Alice` follows her own updates.